# Drag-n-drop between sortable tree menus with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I'm trying to make a sorting interface where there are two different types of groups. Each type can have an unlimited number of groups, and each group can have an unlimited number of items. You should be able to move items between all groups, no matter which type.

I've set up the interface so that the groups show as tree menus, made entirely in CSS, as seen here: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu

When I drag an item outside its container, it disappears behind the other container. I've tried to use the helper: "clone" option in jQuery as well as attempting to set a higher z-index on the item, but it doesn't work.

Also, whenever I grab and drop an item, even if it's in its original place, and then collapse that group the dropped item appears on top of the group name. I'm guessing it doesn't get recognized properly as a child of that group anymore or something along those lines. 
The same also happens if you drop an item on a collapsed group.

Does anyone have a solution to these problems?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kantana/ya63V/8/ 
Long list of code follows.

Javascript (only works within a single group type):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sortable').sortable({
        connectWith: $('.sortable'),
        helper: "clone"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="groupbox" id="groupbox_reports">
    <div class="groupbox_heading">Groups</div>
    <div class="groupbox_wrapper">
        <ol class="tree">
            <li class="group">
                <label for="group1">Group 1: 2013-03-09</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="group1" />
                <ol class="sortable">
                    <li class="file" id="item_1"><a href="">Report 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_3"><a href="">Report 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_6"><a href="">Report 6</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li class="group">
                <label for="group2">Group 2: 2013-03-10</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="group2" />
                <ol class="sortable">
                    <li class="file" id="item_2"><a href="">Report 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_5"><a href="">Report 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_7"><a href="">Report 7</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li class="group">
                <label for="group3">Group 3: 2013-03-11</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="group3" />
                <ol class="sortable">
                    <li class="file" id="item_8"><a href="">Report 8</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_9"><a href="">Report 9</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_10"><a href="">Report 10</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="groupbox_menu">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="groupbox" id="groupbox_incidents">
    <div class="groupbox_heading">Incidents</div>
    <div class="groupbox_wrapper">
        <ol class="tree">
            <li class="group">
                <label for="incident1">Incident 1: 2013-03-12</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="incident1" />
                <ol class="sortable">
                    <li class="file" id="item_11"><a href="">Report 11</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_12"><a href="">Report 12</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_13"><a href="">Report 13</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li class="group">
                <label for="incident2">Incident 2: 2013-03-13</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="incident2" />
                <ol class="sortable">
                    <li class="file" id="item_14"><a href="">Report 14</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_15"><a href="">Report 15</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_16"><a href="">Report 16</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li class="group">
                <label for="incident3">Incident 3: 2013-03-14</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="incident3" />
                <ol class="sortable">
                    <li class="file" id="item_17"><a href="">Report 17</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_18"><a href="">Report 18</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="file" id="item_19"><a href="">Report 19</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="groupbox_menu">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS Tree menu styles */
 ol.tree {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding: 3px;
}
li.group {
    border: 1px dashed;
}
li.file {
    margin-left: -1px !important;
}
li.file a {
    background: url(../img/document.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
li input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    top: 0;
}
li input + ol {
    background: url(../img/toggle-small-expand.png) 40px 0 no-repeat;
    margin: -18px 0 0 -23px;
    /* 15px */
    height: 1em;
}
li input + ol > li {
    display: none;
    margin-left: -14px !important;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
li label {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 37px;
}
li input:checked + ol {
    background: url(../img/toggle-small.png) 40px 5px no-repeat;
    margin: -23px 0 0 -23px;
    /* 20px */
    padding: 1.563em 0 0 80px;
    height: auto;
}
li input:checked + ol > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0.125em;
    /* 2px */
}
li input:checked + ol > li:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 0.063em;
    /* 1px */
}
/** group box **/
 #groupbox {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}
.groupbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.groupbox_wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.groupbox_heading {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #939393;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#groupbox_reports {
    width: 25%;
    border-left: 2px solid #939393;
    border-top: 2px solid #939393;
    border-right: 2px solid #939393;
}
#groupbox_incidents {
    width: 25%;
    border-top: 2px solid #939393;
    border-right: 2px solid #939393;
}
#groupbox_details {
    width: 49%;
    border-top: 2px solid #939393;
    border-right: 2px solid #939393;
}
.groupbox_menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #939393;
}
```